# Neo4j Expected a Node, Relationship or Path, but got a String

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to delete a property from all the nodes that contain that property. The code that I am using is:

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
match (p:Person)
with p limit {limit}
delete p.county
return count(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

but I get the following error: `Expected a Node, Relationship or Path, but got a String` .

Does anyone know what is causing this error and how to solve it?

Comment: Which version are you using? This query works perfectly with 3.0.6 with APOC 3.0.4.2 on an empty database. (Btw is `p.county` might or might not be a typo.)

Comment: Neo4j is 3.0.6 and the APOC is 3.0.4.2.
It is not a typo and also tried deleting another property but I got the same error

Comment: I see. I can indeed reproduce your error by using a single node: `CREATE (p:Person {name: 'p1', county: 'c1'})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cypher documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-delete):

> The DELETE clause is used to delete graph elements — nodes, relationships or paths.

For deleting a property, use the [`REMOVE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-remove) clause:

> The REMOVE clause is used to remove properties and labels from graph elements.

This gives the following query:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("
  MATCH (p:Person)
  WITH p LIMIT {limit}
  REMOVE p.county
", {limit:10000})
```

Strangely, using `RETURN` induces some kind of infinite loop for me, and the query will not terminate, so I removed the `RETURN` clause.